# Get json user_timeline api twitter 1.1

Tags: java, android, json, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm making an app for android that one of its features is a list of the tweets, the tweets I read a json alert that is requested by the twitter api, I'm using version 1.0 of the api, but is limited to 150 for requests per hour, it would be easily popped.

I've been reading a lot of hours on twitter documentation, which frankly sucks, has no real example like facebook documentation, not to mention that there is no manual explaining what each error returned, I am very frustrated with this.

I need a help request using user_timeline Oaut authentication in java

it works [here](https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/NAMEYOURACCOUNT.json):

however is the 1.0 api and without authentication requests de150 the limit is easily popped.

I have no idea how to do this, I'm posting it already researched a lot and not getting any concrete resoltado.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Here's some code I found, maybe it's some help; http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.fi/2011/06/android-twitter-oauth-authentication.html .

Comment: Right now I'm reading the tutorial, seems to be what I need ... I'll try and post here!

Comment: The example solved my problem, adptei for my project and is perfect (at least in as soon an update will come out of the API to all developers causing problems). Post as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a Twitter library like [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html)?  It has OAuth and API version 1.1 support.

Comment: Twitter4j was part of the solution but the User HarisM shortened the way by posting a link to a good example ... But thanks for helping!